# reduce the length of every connected FALSE block to a number of n

Tags: r

Lets generate some reproducible example data:

```
vector <- c()
set.seed(1337)
for (i in 1:3) {
vector <- c(vector,rep(T,sample(4:10,1)),rep(F,sample(1:10,1)))
}
df <- data.frame(bools = vector, values = 1:length(vector))
```

lets print the data:

```
> df
   bools values
1   TRUE      1
2   TRUE      2
3   TRUE      3
4   TRUE      4
5   TRUE      5
6   TRUE      6
7   TRUE      7
8   TRUE      8
9  FALSE      9
10 FALSE     10
11 FALSE     11
12 FALSE     12
13 FALSE     13
14 FALSE     14
15  TRUE     15
16  TRUE     16
17  TRUE     17
18  TRUE     18
19 FALSE     19
20 FALSE     20
21 FALSE     21
22 FALSE     22
23 FALSE     23
24  TRUE     24
25  TRUE     25
26  TRUE     26
27  TRUE     27
28  TRUE     28
29  TRUE     29
30 FALSE     30
31 FALSE     31
32 FALSE     32
33 FALSE     33
>
```

The rules are: (n = 2 in the following example)

1. Keep all TRUE rows
2. A FALSE block if "longer" than n=2 will be reduced to n = 2
3. Keep the first n = 2 rows of that "too long" FALSE-Block

applying the rules with result in the following dataframe: df.new

```
df.new <- df[c(1:10,15:20,24:31),]
> df.new
   bools values
1   TRUE      1
2   TRUE      2
3   TRUE      3
4   TRUE      4
5   TRUE      5
6   TRUE      6
7   TRUE      7
8   TRUE      8
9  FALSE      9
10 FALSE     10
15  TRUE     15
16  TRUE     16
17  TRUE     17
18  TRUE     18
19 FALSE     19
20 FALSE     20
24  TRUE     24
25  TRUE     25
26  TRUE     26
27  TRUE     27
28  TRUE     28
29  TRUE     29
30 FALSE     30
31 FALSE     31
>
```

How can i reduce df to df.new? Please keep in mind that a FALSE-Block can be "smaller" than n and in that case we will keep that FALSE-Block unchanged.

Comment: Do *you* have any ideas?

Comment: i have no idea how to tell R automatically that 1:8 is a T-Block, 9:14 is a F-Block and so on. So that R always knows adjacent T or F form a distinct block. If i knew that i could come up with a solution i think.

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.0/topics/rleid

Comment: thank you, that rleidv command can get me somewhere i think. Let me try!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another similar solution could be :

```
library(plyr)
library(data.table)
df$id <- rleid(df$bools)
ddply(df, .(id), function(x) if(x$bools[1]){x}else{x[1:min(2, sum(!x$bools)),]})
```

---

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df$id <- rleid(df$bools) 
df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
       slice(if(bools[1]){1:n()}else{1:min(2, sum(!bools))})
```

Comment: after a long time I'm using `plyr` since getting addicted to `dplyr`. I'm seeking for a solution in `dplyr` or `data.table`

Comment: > ddply(df, .(id), function(x) if(x$bools[1]){x}else{x[1:2,]})
Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors

Comment: you have to use for eg the head function, since a F-block can also have a length smaller n=2. If you use x[1:2,] it can get out of bound. If you correct that i will check it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

With the valuable help of Roland, i came up with following working (in my opinion ugly) solution:

with the use of rleidv() and n times duplicate()

```
n=2

df$blocks <- rleidv(df$bools)

df$blocks[df$bools %in% T] <- NA

for (i in 1:n) {
df$blocks[duplicated(df$blocks) %in% F] <- NA
}

df.new <- df[is.na(df$blocks),1:2]
```

print result

```
> df.new
   bools values
1   TRUE      1
2   TRUE      2
3   TRUE      3
4   TRUE      4
5   TRUE      5
6   TRUE      6
7   TRUE      7
8   TRUE      8
9  FALSE      9
10 FALSE     10
15  TRUE     15
16  TRUE     16
17  TRUE     17
18  TRUE     18
19 FALSE     19
20 FALSE     20
24  TRUE     24
25  TRUE     25
26  TRUE     26
27  TRUE     27
28  TRUE     28
29  TRUE     29
30 FALSE     30
31 FALSE     31
>
```

Comment: `setDT(df); df[, if(!bools && .N > 2) .(bools = bools[1:2], values = values[1:2])  else .(bools = bools, values = values), by = rleid(bools)]`

Comment: a combination of Roland, Imo and joel.wilson gives me the appealing solution: ddply(df, .(rleidv(df$bools)), function(x) if(x$bools[1]){x}else{head(x,n)})[2:3]

Answer (score 1):

A base R alternative, (that is still pretty ugly) that uses the split-apply-combine methodology is

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, cumsum(c(1,abs(diff(df$bools))))),
                      function(i) if(!i[1, "bools"]) head(i, 2) else i))
```

df is split using `cumsum(c(1,abs(diff(df$bools))))` which is a base R version of `data.table`'s `rleid` function. Each subset of df (now stored in a list is checked as to whether or not it is a TRUE block or FALSE block using `if ... else` if a FALSE block, then `head(i, 2)` keeps the first two observations of the block. Otherwise, the full block is returned. The resulting data.frames are then combined with `do.call` and `rbind`.

Also, note that `head(i, n)` will return i without change if `length` or `nrow` of i is less than n.

```
head(1, 2)
[1] 1
```

This code returns

```
     bools values
1.1   TRUE      1
1.2   TRUE      2
1.3   TRUE      3
1.4   TRUE      4
1.5   TRUE      5
1.6   TRUE      6
1.7   TRUE      7
1.8   TRUE      8
2.9  FALSE      9
2.10 FALSE     10
3.15  TRUE     15
3.16  TRUE     16
3.17  TRUE     17
3.18  TRUE     18
4.19 FALSE     19
4.20 FALSE     20
5.24  TRUE     24
5.25  TRUE     25
5.26  TRUE     26
5.27  TRUE     27
5.28  TRUE     28
5.29  TRUE     29
6.30 FALSE     30
6.31 FALSE     31
```

Comment: apart from the cumsum command its a great and understandable solution for me. Thank you :-)